# Are north and west parameters in rasterio.transform.from_origin() in pixel space?

Tags: python, geospatial, gdal, rasterio

I'm looking for some clarification on the use of the function
`rasterio.transform.from_origin(west, north, xsize, ysize)`.

I'm looking to re-project a tensor back into a coordinate system. It is unclear to me what units(lat/lon?) the north and west parameters of from_origin are! I used the lat/lon coordinates but the imagery was projected to the wrong location.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are in projection coordinates. See [here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#dataset-georeferencing).

You may find [this exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279953/numpy-array-to-gtiff-using-rasterio-without-source-raster) useful as well.